# Does the antecedent of ‘you’ shift in Labouchère’s poem “The Brown Man’s Burden”?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, literature, poetry, antecedents

I was reading [Henry Labouchère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Labouch%C3%A8re)’s
poem [“The Brown Man’s Burden”](http://www.swans.com/library/art8/xxx074.html)
first published in 1899. I was a little confused
because at one point the antecedent for *ye/you*
appears to switch from the white men to the brown men
(meaning the Philippine natives).

For example, in the poem’s second stanza,

> Pile on the brown man’s burden;
> And, if **ye** rouse his hate,
> Meet his old-fashioned reasons
> With Maxims up to date.
> With shells and dumdum bullets
> A hundred times made plain
> The brown man’s loss must ever
> Imply the white man’s gain.

Here, the second-person *ye* pronoun seems to be referring
to the natives (the brown men), while the third-person
possessive pronoun *his* in *his hate* seems now to refer
to the white men.

However, in all other parts of the poem, the second-person
*you* seems to refer to the white men not to the brown
ones, as in the poem’s opening couplet reading:

> Pile on the brown man’s burden
> To gratify **your** greed.

Please let me know whether I am analyzing the intended
antecedents of these pronouns correctly here.

Comment: Why don't you think "you" still refers to white men? If you (white men) rouse the brown man's anger, answer the brown man's old fashioned reasons with your modern Maxims. (A pun on the contemporary gun.)

Comment: Just for that sentence, it says if "you" rouse his hate, you will meet his old fashioned reasons with maxims. Isn't this meaning that if you, the natives, arouse the White men's hate, the natives will receive the fiery guns (maxim can refer to guns) from the White men?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess the "you" here can still refer to white men, but then the natives would have "old-fashioned reasons" and the maxim guns. Does that still make sense?

Comment: No. The brown men's old-fashioned reasons will be **met** (answered) by the white man's Maxims.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you so much. Is there any way I can mark your comment as answer or give you some points?

Comment: I gather clicking the little up-arrow-chevron thing to the left of a comment tosses its writer a bone, but I can't say I've ever had one ;-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian write your comments into an answer and you'll get a few of those clicky thingies. It is surprisingly satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any change of antecedent:

Pile on the brown man’s burden; -> (imperative) Ye - **the white man** - should pile on (=increase) the brown man’s burden *(of work and/or troubles)*

And, if ye rouse his hate, -> and, *[start parentheses]* if, by doing this, you - **the white man** - rouse his **the brown man's** hate *[end parentheses]*

Meet his old-fashioned reasons -> (imperative) you - **the white man** - should counter his - **the brown man's** - old fashioned reasons for complaining

With Maxims up to date. -> with a modern machine gun.

> Here, the second-person ye pronoun seems to be referring to the natives (the brown men), while the third-person possessive pronoun his in his hate seems now to refer to the white men.

No. It means if you - the white man - rouse his - the brown man's - hate, i.e. if you make the brown man angry.

Historically, slaves outnumbered the slave owners and the slave owners were in a state of constant anxiety that the slaves would rebel. The slave-owners therefore took the strongest measures to control their slaves.

Comment: Thanks, done...

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right, since the white man used to tell
the world that he brings enlightenment to the dark,
colonized lands. Then this state might refer to
the moments when the natives resisted and asked for
their independence, the white man refused and mentioned
the old-fashioned reasons he used to tell the world
in order to justify staying in the natives’ lands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My English dad used to point out that a lot of white men in England were far from white men in those days, working at the furnaces of the Industrial Revolution, on the railways, down mines. And as for the chimney-sweeps .... 'White man' in some passages is so broad-brush as to be arguably racist.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth reminded me  of "Golden lads and girls all must,  as chimney sweeps come to dust"..or something like that.

Comment: @Cascabel I was never quite sure where the man with the dancing bear fitted into the great scheme of things. It's _so_ hard to marry decent lyrics with a marvellous harmony.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the actual question.